# Selectively accept edits in git in visual studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I'm using git locally for this MVC5 project that I'm working on. The UI person isn't using any source control or visual studio. The way it works is - I upload the views to FTP where he makes his changes. Then I am expected to download in my local system (which overwrites any changes I did since my last upload to FTP) and merge the changes. So basically, since I'm working in parallel on the same files, he ends up working on older versions of the same files.

But thankfully, in almost all cases, the UI changes are in no conflict with my own changes, i.e., they're in different parts of the file than my changes. So, what I'm looking to do is to be able to somehow commit the changes *selectively*.  For example, visual studio shows the changes in "Compare with Umodified", is it possible to go over each highlighted change and accept/reject for commit?

Alternatively (but not preferably), is it possible to to inspect the changes and merge/commit all changes from both versions into the main branch?

I have no experience with commandline use of git so I'm really looking to achieve this from within visual studio, if possible.

Below is one example -

Original version -

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Balance</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
</div>
```

My version after my updates - (I just changed model.Id to model.Name and added a foreach loop)

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Balance</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @foreach(var item in model.Items) {<span>@item.Name</span>}
    </div>
</div>
```

His version after his changes - (he just added a new class called tableview in the top div)

```
<div class="form-horizontal tableview">
    <h4>Balance</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the changes are in separate parts of the files.

Comment: Have your changes been committed to your local repository already?  Or are they just sitting in your working folder?

Comment: Best option: make them use git. Next best option: use branch and merge strategy, and every time you push to FTP that is a merge to the "ftp" branch. Any changes from the other dev goes on top of the ftp branch (in other words, "fake" them using git by making the commits they would make on top of what they get via FTP).

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you at least try the `git-gui` which will give you a visual ui interface to the current changes in the file, and you can from that ui select the specific hunks or lines that you want included in your next commit.

I use it all the time with other tools (e.g. Matlab*) that don't immediately know about the VCS integration.

I can pick out my coarse ad-hoc changes and make them look like a considered sequence of small steps! (and the bad lines can be omitted from the VCS record)

(*) Matlab does have some VCS aware capability, but not at this granularity.